# Compare two cells and copy them / 2 workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I hope someone can help me.. I am a beginner and sit here since 5 hours to do this work :(

I need to compare two cells. When the Cell 1 have the same value than Cell 2 i have to copy the value into the next 3 cells next to cell 2. When they aren't the same value, then the loop should go one cell down. And this down to the last filled cell.

Workbook 1 have the range G1:G100 this should be compared with the Workbook 2 and range B1:100

If the the content is the same in both, then i have to copy the 3 next cells next to the WB2 range where the cells are similar C1:E100

And thats the code i have

```
Public Sub zusammenführen()
Dim cell As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("T:\folder\LWTP.xlsx")

For Each cell In wb1.Sheets(1).Range("G1:G100")
    If ActiveCell.Value = wb2.Sheets("LWTP").Range("B1:B100").Value Then
    MsgBox "Test"

    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

I hope you understand my english Thanks for help!

Comment: `ActiveCell.Value` should be `cell.Value` so it uses the variable from your loop `For Each cell`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks, but then i get an error: runtime error 13

Comment: You may want a check for `IsError(cell.Value)` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub zusammenführen()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook, ws2 as worksheet

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook   
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("T:\folder\LWTP.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("LWTP") 

    For Each cell In wb1.Sheets(1).Range("G1:G100")
        If cell.Value = ws2.Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value Then

            cell.offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
                ws2.Cells(cell.Row, "C").Resize(1, 3).Value

        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, now i get a runtime error 1004 on the line:
If cell.Value = ws2.Range(cell.Row, "B").Value Then 

     The method "range" for the object _worksheet is failed

Comment: @Mike replace both `ws2.Range` with `ws2.Cells`.

Comment: Nice, it works now, can i add the copy command now to the end of the if?